# SQL Update then Select, Selects the original value

Tags: c#, sql-server, ajax, entity-framework, async-await

I have a super basic EF method that basically just does:

```
var obj = context.Set<Objs>().Single(x => x.ID = id);
obj.varBinaryMax = largeByteArray;
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The method is `async Task<...> UpdateObj()`

The method calling THAT is an `async Task<...>`, which has an `await` when calling UpdateObj().

There are awaits all the way down to a WebAPI Call which is:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateObj(...)
```

Of course the call to the method chain in the WebAPI is also awaited.

When stepping through the code, everything is definitely slow, because I'm talking about multiple megabytes of `Byte[]` for this update.  That may or may not be the issue.

The UI is using JQuery to make this call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://dubs.website.com/api/Object/Edit/' + someID,
    data: someImageBytes,
    success: function () {
        alert('lol, all done');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('lol, error');
    }
});
```

The problem is... if I refresh the page, which then queries the database for the image bytes, I get back an unaltered old image.  Unless I wait about 10 seconds, then refresh, then I get back the updated image.

But, for sure, my update calls all finished, were awaited, and updated the database.  So why, for some number of seconds, am I being returned an old object?  My WebAPI call to retrieve the object is NOT Caching the original object.

Is SQL server taking a while to update that VarBinary(MAX) field, even after it returns completion?

Comment: It depends on how you retrieve that image to begin with. It could be that it is cached in the browser and the browser is deciding to just retrieve it from cache instead of going to the server. This caching has nothing to do with your Web API caching or not. You could test this theory by changing the URL by adding a random variable in the query string or some other cache busting trick.

Comment: @Igor A breakpoint hits all the way back to the EF call to retrieve the object.  What you're saying might still be true, if you say that's possible... but that would mean the call completes all the way through, the image is returned, then the browser ignores it?

Comment: If you see that the returned image server side is different than the image being displayed in the call then yes, that is the case (unlikely though). Generally if the browser cache is being used the call will not be made at all.

Comment: Right.  Unfortunately, VS doesn't have an image viewer when looking at a bytearray property.  Also, doing a manual swap to Base64 yields too large of a string for VS to show me, and still too large for my clipboard for me to move it to an `img` viewer somewhere.  So I can't currently tell what the image is when debugging.  But like you said, it's making and completing the call.  That's why I assume it has something to do with SQL Server.